# Use a checkbox to open another excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have 2 checkboxes, one that says "Summary" and the other "Breakdown". When the user checks either one or both of the boxes, it needs to open another excel file with name "Summary Template" and "Breakdown Template" respectively and eventually "Save As" NAME (ID). How do I go about doing so? Thanks in advance!

```
If Summary Then
    Debug.Print "You Checked Summary"
    MyPath = "C:\Users\valerie\Desktop\"Summary Template.xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open (MyPath)
    'Am stuck here on how to save as file

ElseIf Breakdown Then
    Debug.Print "You Checked Breakdown"
    MyPath = "C:\Users\valerie\Desktop\"Breakdown Template.xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open (MyPath)

ElseIf Summary = 0 And Breakdown = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please Select Report Type"
End If
```

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thank you! my apologies, I understand where you're coming from. I've edited, and I've only managed to close and save but not change the name

Comment: [There is Microsoft documentation on the `SaveAs` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas)

Comment: @TimStack I've looked it up and attempted to do this where wsa is the workbook i opened and activated "summaryn = wsa.SaveAs("C:\Users\valerie\Desktop\Template" & tbAC, xlsx)" but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Valwrie if you read the documentation that Tim linked you will find the section about `FileFormat` which tells what to specify there ([XlFileFormat enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat)). `xlsx` is not a valid value for `FileFormat`. Also see my answer below. Always read the documentations carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following and read [SaveAs method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas):

```
Dim wb As Workbook

If Summary Then
    Debug.Print "You Checked Summary"
    MyPath = "C:\Users\valerie\Desktop\Summary Template.xlsx"
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath) 'set workbook to a variable that you can use to access it

    wb.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\valerie\Desktop\XXXX.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
     'check documentation for how to use it.

ElseIf Breakdown Then
    Debug.Print "You Checked Breakdown"
    MyPath = "C:\Users\valerie\Desktop\Breakdown Template.xlsx"
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath)

ElseIf Summary = 0 And Breakdown = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please Select Report Type"
End If
```

Note that ther was an additional `"` between your path and file name (in your question) that has to be removed.

Comment: @Peh thank you! I've eventually used 'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\valerie\Desktop\Template" & "\" & NName & NIC & ".xlsx" ' where NName and NIC are strings

Comment: @Valwrie I recommend to stay away from `ActiveWorkbook` which can easily change by a click of the user. The method I showed with the `wb` variable is much more reliable and cannot be interfered by a user's click.